# Find all values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that this inequality forces $f$ to be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, r>0, M>0\ni |z|\ge r \text{ and } |f(z)|\le M|z|^{\alpha}$. I need to find all values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that this inequality forces $f$ to be constant. Thanks for helping. $f$ is an entire function.

I think I should consider $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^{\alpha}}\implies |g|\le M$, $g$ is entire ?

Comment: Is $f$ an entire function?

Comment: yessssssssssssmm

Comment: The answer is $\alpha <1$. Be careful with $z^\alpha$ for complex $z$. You certainly proved Liouville's theorem in your course. Look at that proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an expansion on Jochen's remark. Since $f$ is entire, write 
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$$
where $$a_k=\frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{k+1}}\ d\zeta.$$
Here $\partial B(0,r)$ is the circle centered at $0$ and with radius $r>0$. Then 
$$|a_k|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{|f(\zeta)|}{|\zeta|^{k+1}}\ |d\zeta|\leq\oint_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{1}{2\pi}M|\zeta|^{\alpha-k-1}\ |d\zeta|
\leq Mr^{\alpha-k}.$$
Thus if $\alpha<1$, then for all $k\geq 1$, letting $r\to\infty$ in the above estimate, we get $a_k=0$, which implies that $f$ is a constant.

If $\alpha\geq 1$, then there are non-constant polynomials that satisfy the properties listed for $f$.

Thus $\alpha<1$.